# where are the log files saved in axis2 webservice

Tags: tomcat, web-services, log4j, apache-axis

i have put log4j.properties file into WEB-INF/classes folder in my axis 2 webservice. now i can see logs been printed on console. but i have also put file appender. but i can not find the log file anywhere. could someone help me to find a solution for this problem.

> log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA, FA
>   #Console Appender log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r
>   [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
>   #File Appender log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>   log4j.appender.FA.File=ws.log
>   log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r
>   [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
>   # Set the logger level of File Appender to WARN
>   log4j.appender.FA.Threshold = WARN

Comment: Could you post the configuration of the file appender

Comment: i have edited my question with the content of log4j.properties file. sorry for the delay to respond to your question

Comment: Is it just the formatting, or is this line commented in your actual properties? "log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"

Comment: And can you try giving a fully qualified path to ws.log?